# How to remove statusbar height in React-native or Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to remove `StatusBar` height.

So although I succeeded in trying not to look like **hidden**, the height of the `status bar` still remains. I want to get rid of this `statusbar` height.

```js
  <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
...
```

Use StatusBar.currentHeight but didn't work.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  StatusBar.currentHeight = 0
}
```

[image: statusbar see]
[image: statusbar Not see]

> **How do I get rid of StatusBar area?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Small library that helps you to get status bar height and modification.

**Install**

```
npm install --save react-native-status-bar-height
```

OR

```
yarn add react-native-status-bar-height
```

**Usage getStatusBarHeight(skipAndroid: boolean = false)**

```
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-status-bar-height';


// 44 - on iPhoneX
// 20 - on iOS device
// X - on Android platfrom (runtime value)
// 0 - on all other platforms (default)
console.log(getStatusBarHeight());

// will be 0 on Android, because You pass true to skipAndroid
console.log(getStatusBarHeight(true));
```

[refer here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height)

[For Example](https://github.com/ovr/react-native-status-bar-height#readme)

Comment: I don't know if I'm successful because I haven't tried, but thank you for your good opinion. I want to download as few modules as possible and write an app.